# How to write multilines to a file with fish?

Tags: cat, fish

In `bash`, I can do:

```
cat >a.txt <<EOF
line 1111
line 2222
EOF
```

But this is invalid syntax when using in `fish`. What's the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use echo and a multiline string (adapted from [this thread in the fish issue tracker](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/540#issuecomment-13918363))

```
echo >a.txt "\
line 1111
line 2222"
```

Answer (score 7):

FWIW in the console/terminal I have always used:

```
cat > a.txt
line 1111
line 2222
Ctrl+D
```

It worked both in Bash and Fish.

Comment: Thanks for this good approach, it's very handy for daily work

Comment: Still want to know the how to do it without pressing `ctrl+D`, since I can use it in script file